# How do I implement an ajax-style loading panel in my wpf app?

Tags: wpf, panel

I am calling a wcf service, so I'd like to display a spinner of some type so the user can see an operation is occurring.  I'm wondering is somebody has some examples to look at.

EDIT:
this is what I was looking for:
[Spinning Progress Control in WPF](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0875ebf8-bb77-45ea-a929-d40743a3bf03/)

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for PriorityBinding.  -- You can bind to a spinning animation, and then to actual data once it is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for an [asynchronous pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx) for your call?

1. Kick off WPF app's WCF
2. Display animation
3. Wait for WCF call to return
4. Hide animation

Comment: yes I am making an async call, but want some ideas for a control that displays an animation

Comment: Honestly, I always just used animated gifs in a picture box (I'm sorry all my code is at my prior job).  I think it was just a matter of finding the images.  Most of the time we had access to an artist to do the work, sometimes google.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this [user control](http://huydinhpham.blogspot.com/2011/07/wpf-loading-panel.html) which may help, it will display messages with a progress bar spinning to show it is currently loading something.

```
  <ctr:LoadingPanel x:Name="loadingPanel"
                    IsLoading="{Binding PanelLoading}"
                    Message="{Binding PanelMainMessage}"
                    SubMessage="{Binding PanelSubMessage}" 
                    ClosePanelCommand="{Binding PanelCloseCommand}" />
```

It has a couple of basic properties that you can bind to.

Comment: This is [another example](http://huydinhpham.blogspot.com/2013/06/mahapps-flyout-loading-panel.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but for what it's worth I've been using the BusyIndicator class from the Extended WPF Toolkit for this kind of problem. It provides a clean way to overlay your controls with a dynamic visual indicator that you an extend as much as you wish. Here's the link with more details and some screenshots:

[BusyIndicator docs on CodePlex](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator&referringTitle=Home)

...and the author of the control also provides [a nice write up around how it can be used](http://elegantcode.com/2011/10/07/extended-wpf-toolkitusing-the-busyindicator/).